# Is a 36 gallon bow shaped tank okay for baby turtles?

Tags: turtles, containment

I'm planning to buy hatchling or baby turtles and working out for a good home for them. I'm going to get a 36 gallon bow shaped tank but not sure if there are any specifics/dimensions I should follow while buying a tank especially to have baby turtles. Also, not sure if 36 gallon tank is too big for them to withstand.

Turtle Breed: Mud/Musk

Appreciate any additional suggestions reg this.

Comment: You should have in mind the grown size of you baby turtles. If you give them a big enough tank at beginning you do not need to buy a second if they grow. The water level is the one thing that will grow with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

36 Gallons is a good size for baby turtles. If you are keeping the turtles to a larger size you definitely want to upgrade the size of the tank. Turtles like to roam. Width and Length are more important than height. For example a 40 gallon breeder tank is something I always recommend to new turtle owners. As long as they have enough room to swim and a basking spot out of the water that is big enough for multiple turtles, a filter, and a heater they should be fine.